# Try to use hdf5dotnet in C#program , but visual studio show me “System.IO.FileNotFoundException” can't load “HDF5DotNet.dll”

Tags: c#, hdf5, hdf5dotnet

when i use hdf5dotnet in my C# programe, it's show something about System.IO.FileNotFoundException with HDF5DotNet.dll

Comment: How do you include the DLL in your program?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are unable to determine your problem if you don't share more details. For example how you include the dll